# Change UIPageViewController Flip Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios

I have an `UIPageViewController` that changes `ViewControllers` with page flip animation on default

[image]

Is it possible to replace this animation with simple slide-in/slide-out one? Like Android `ViewPager` does for example.

Here is my `UIPageViewController` initialization:

```
var pageViewController = new UIPageViewController();
        pageViewController.DataSource = new InfoViewControllerDataSource(this, _pageTitles);
        pageViewController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { Pages[0] }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, null);
        pageViewController.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, _toolbar.Frame.Bottom, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height);
        AddChildViewController(this.pageViewController);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it from the Interface builder. Change the Transition style property to Scroll. If you want to do it programmatically, transitionStyle is a read-only property. It can only be done by [this method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614105-init)

```
pageViewController = new UIPageViewController(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scr‌​oll, UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal)
```

Comment: thanks, adding style in constructor did the job.
you can add this line `pageViewController = new UIPageViewController(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal);` in your answer to make it easier for others to find the answer.

Comment: If the viewController not programmatically created and is subclassed from UIPageViewController, then we can use this method as well.

`- (UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle)transitionStyle {
    return UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll;
}`

Answer (score 4):

Can do within the storyboard :
Page view Controller

Navigation :  Horizontal

Transition Style : Scroll

[image]